# call a function when changing a QSpinBox value

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 2 QSpinBox'es - **horTilesNum** and **verTilesNum**. The value of the horizontal one should always be 1.5 times bigger than the number of the vertical one. So when the value of one of those Spinboxes is changed the value of another Spinbox should be updated. I have 2 functions for that but I don't know how to call them when Spinbox values are chenged

```
self.horTilesNum= QSpinBox(self)
self.horTilesNum.setRange(2,1000)
self.horTilesNum.setStyleSheet("QSpinBox {"
                                           "width: 30px;"
                                           "}")
self.horTilesNum.move(880, 178)


self.verTilesNum = QSpinBox(self)
self.verTilesNum.setRange(2,1000)
self.verTilesNum.setStyleSheet("QSpinBox {"
                                           "width: 30px;"
                                           "}")
self.verTilesNum.move(880, 203)



def update_hor_tiles_spinbox(self):
    print("horizontal changed")

def update_ver_tiles_spinbox(self):
    print("vertical changed")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```py
self.horTilesNum.valueChanged.connect(self.update_hor_tiles_spinbox)
self.verTilesNum.valueChanged.connect(self.update_ver_tiles_spinbox)
```

Comment: how can I pass argument to the functions?

Comment: change the function signature from update_ver_tiles_spinbox(self) to update_ver_tiles_spinbox(self, value), value will receive the current value of the spinbox

Comment: it's not easy to describe the problem in the comment section.... but I tried excactly what you said and it doesn't work correctly. After QSpinBox changeValue calls a function the whole script stops. But the function is called and returns it's result. And after that the script stops

Comment: could you share the code?

Comment: `def add_image(self):
       self.verTilesNumSpin.valueChanged.connect(self.update_hor_tiles_spinbox(self.uploaded_img_width, self.uploaded_img_height))
            self.horTilesNumSpin.valueChanged.connect(self.update_ver_tiles_spinbox(self.uploaded_img_width, self.uploaded_img_height))


def update_hor_tiles_spinbox(self, hor, vert):
    print(hor, vert)

def update_ver_tiles_spinbox(self, hor, vert):
    print(hor, vert)`

Comment: The problem here is, you should only give the name of the method inside connect, not call it. like connect(self.update_hor_tiles_spinbox) and access the values of self.uploaded_img_width and self.uploaded_img_height from the self.update_hor_tiles_spinbox() method